# How to pull data from a list which contains URLs and to display in a webpage(webpart) as a quick links

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Using SharePoint-2013
I have a list which contains URLs and I have a webpage. Now what I need is to pull the data(URLs) from the list and need to display them as a links.

The links in the web page must be collected from the list and should be clickable.
List may have many URLs but the top 10 should be displayed

The links should come under an image having a title.
Is this possible using SharePoint Designer or SharePoint out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 1):

Following are some OOTB ways to achieve it

**1. Content Query Webpart:**

This is OOTB webpart we can use to query & display data from the list. There are few predefined templates to show data. But, If you want something different style then you can create your own custom item style template from sharepoint designer.

**2. Content search webpart:**

This webpart introduced in SharePoint 2013 & its will return the data faster as compared to content query webpart compared to content query Webpart. This one is specially designed for cross site contents but still you can show data from single list. Here also you can create custom control templates and item templates.

**3. Promoted links App:**

The Promoted Links app in SharePoint 2013 is a very simple and useful. This app displays links as icons or tiles on a web page once the web part is added. You can add this app from Site Content--> Add an App--> Promoted links. Once added to site then open this app add items with links,backgrounds,titles & finally go to page where you want to display these links then edit the page and add that"Promoted Links" webpart on page.

**4.Content editor webpart:**

This webpart is OOTB but you have to create your own Javascript and html code and embed within it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Content Query webpart (under Content Rollup web part group), select the desired list, any filtering condition and show the information.